# An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild: No such file or directory

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm seeing the following error when running `dotnet build` of my solution in a Concourse Docker container. The same image works fine locally and the output of `dotnet --info` is identical, with the exception of "arm64" vs "amd64".

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.03
MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: No such file or directory
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.LaunchNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.LaunchNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.GetNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs, Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Int64 hostHandshake, Int64 clientHandshake, NodeContextTerminateDelegate terminateNode)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.ProcessPacket(Int32 node, INodePacket packet)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass70_0.<Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketHandler.PacketReceived>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.ProcessWorkQueue(Action action)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.EndBuild()
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, Dictionary`2 restoreProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, TextWriter targetsWriter, Boolean detailedSummary, ISet`1 warningsAsErrors, ISet`1 warningsAsMessages, Boolean enableRestore, ProfilerLogger profilerLogger, Boolean enableProfiler, Boolean interactive, Boolean isolateProjects, Boolean graphBuild, Boolean lowPriority, String[] inputResultsCaches, String outputResultsCache)

MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: No such file or directory
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.LaunchNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, Dictionary`2 restoreProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, TextWriter targetsWriter, Boolean detailedSummary, ISet`1 warningsAsErrors, ISet`1 warningsAsMessages, Boolean enableRestore, ProfilerLogger profilerLogger, Boolean enableProfiler, Boolean interactive, Boolean isolateProjects, Boolean graphBuild, Boolean lowPriority, String[] inputResultsCaches, String outputResultsCache)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: No such file or directory
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.LaunchNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, Dictionary`2 restoreProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, TextWriter targetsWriter, Boolean detailedSummary, ISet`1 warningsAsErrors, ISet`1 warningsAsMessages, Boolean enableRestore, ProfilerLogger profilerLogger, Boolean enableProfiler, Boolean interactive, Boolean isolateProjects, Boolean graphBuild, Boolean lowPriority, String[] inputResultsCaches, String outputResultsCache)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main(String[] args)
```

The error is about a missing file, but nowhere does it say which file it is. I tried running the same command with detailed / diagnostic logs (`-v d / diag`) but that didn't show anything useful. I'm not sure why the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue I ran the following

```
ln -s / /rootfs
```

I found this solution after trying to build a new project in Concourse using `dotnet new "Class Library"` and then `dotnet build`. For some reason the error for this new project actually contained the path of the "missing" file.

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.417/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "/rootfs/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet" is invalid. [/tmp/build/04d13fd0/foo/foo.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.417/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "/rootfs/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet" is invalid. [/tmp/build/04d13fd0/foo/foo.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I have no idea why it's looking for a file under `/rootfs` - there's no such directory on this machine or on my local machine (where `dotnet build` works). I suspect it's something to do with the underlying OS Concourse is running on.